# how to set up laptop microphone to use with speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

i tried to transform my speech in text with speech recognition, but nothing work, when i use this command python3 -m speech_recognition all work good

this is the output of command

```
A moment of silence, please...
Set minimum energy threshold to 504.318206261492
Say something!
Got it! Now to recognize it...
Oops! Didn't catch that
Say something!
Got it! Now to recognize it...
You said Orange
Say something!
Got it! Now to recognize it...
Oops! Didn't catch that
```

this is code that didnt work

```py
import speech_recognition as sr 
r=sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
     print("say")
     audio=r.listen(source)
query=r.recognize_google(audio)
print("you say  "+query)
```

i tried to detect what microphone i use with this code

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))
```

this is the output but all of them didnt work

```
Microphone with name "HDA Intel PCH: ALC271X Analog (hw:0,0)" found for `Microphone(device_index=0)`
Microphone with name "HDA Intel PCH: ALC271X Alt Analog (hw:0,2)" found for `Microphone(device_index=1)`
Microphone with name "HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 0 (hw:0,3)" found for `Microphone(device_index=2)`
Microphone with name "sysdefault" found for `Microphone(device_index=3)`
Microphone with name "front" found for `Microphone(device_index=4)`
Microphone with name "surround40" found for `Microphone(device_index=5)`
Microphone with name "surround51" found for `Microphone(device_index=6)`
Microphone with name "surround71" found for `Microphone(device_index=7)`
Microphone with name "hdmi" found for `Microphone(device_index=8)`
Microphone with name "pulse" found for `Microphone(device_index=9)`
Microphone with name "dmix" found for `Microphone(device_index=10)`
Microphone with name "default" found for `Microphone(device_index=11)`
```

Comment: So, which of the devices is your microphone (connected to)?

Comment: i dont know, i use built in laptop microphone, but i tried to use all of them from index=0 to index=11 and none work

Comment: what means "didnt work" ? did you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you can always get path to this module `speech_recognition.__file__` and check how it works when you run it with `python3 -m speech_recognition`. Code could be in this file in `if __name__ == "__main__"`

Comment: I found this code in module but other file `__main__.py` and it uses `m = sr.Microphone()` without device number